# Initialize vector of structures

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, structure

Let's I have

```
struct Vector {

    float i,j,k;
}
```

I want to zero all elements of vec declared below (i,j,k=0)

```
std::vector <Vector> vec;
vec.resize(num,0);
```

I don't want to use reserve() and then push_back() zeroes one by one.
Another thing is, after succesfully initializing vec, I want to set all members of vec to zero again after it is manipulated. Is there something like memset for vectors?

**EDIT:**
I compared all of the methods in Mike Seymour's and Xeo's answers and as a result 
`size_t size = vec.size();
vec.clear();
vec.resize(size);` is the fastest if they are repeated frequently in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's very simple:

```
vec.resize(num);
```

or initialise it with the required size:

```
std::vector<Vector> vec(num);
```

Both the constructor and `resize` will fill new elements with value-initialised objects. A value-initialised object of a type with no default constructor (such as your `Vector`) will have all numeric members initialised to zero.

To reset everything to zero, either

```
size_t size = vec.size();
vec.clear();
vec.resize(size);
```

or:

```
std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Vector());
```

or, less efficiently but with a strong exception guarantee:

```
std::vector<Vector>(vec.size()).swap(vec);
```

Comment: Regarding reseting, which one is faster, vec.clear... or fill...?

Comment: @Shibli: They're almost certainly very similar in speed. If it's important to you, then you'll have to measure them. If speed really matters, you might find that `memset` is slightly faster (see Xeo's answer), but more dangerous since it will break in undefined ways if you modify your type so that it's no longer POD. Again, the only way to tell whether it's actually faster is to measure it.

Answer (score 1):

C++ way of setting all current elements to `0`:

```
 std::fill( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0 );
```

Or, alternatively, to re-initialize to a given size:

```
 vec.clear();
 vec.resize(num, 0);
```

This might not be as performant as `memset`, but good enough for 99% of the cases.

Comment: Should I include 0 in vec.resize(num, 0)? Because Mike Seymour did not do that.

Comment: He explains the implicit initialization in his answer. Using the default constructor (without 0) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* just use `memset`, so long your `Vector` is a POD type:

```
std::vector<Vector> v(num, 0); // inital fill
// do stuff
memset(&v[0], 0, sizeof(Vector) * v.size());
```

Though the C++ version would be with `std::fill`

```
#include <algorithm>

std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Comment: What happends if it is C++ version or way? What happens if it is in other way?

Comment: @Shibli: `std::fill` will work for any type that you can put in a `vector`. `memset` is only valid for plain data (POD) types; it will break if the type has constructors, destructors, virtual functions or other complications.

Comment: @Shibli: You can use `memset` for character types (`char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`); I don't think it's guaranteed for any others (although I've never seen an implementation where it would fail for other integral or floating point types).  Globally, it's very bad practice; `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` works for all types (and is likely to be slightly more efficient).